# python setuptools doesn't understand that 'google-api-python-client' is really the module name

Tags: python, setuptools, google-api-python-client

I get the following error because of the naming convention used by Google with their apiclient module:

```
$ sudo ./setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 37, in <module>
    scripts = [ 'bin/gsync' ],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 225, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 259, in __init__
    getattr(self.metadata, "set_" + key)(val)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 1220, in set_requires
    distutils.versionpredicate.VersionPredicate(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/versionpredicate.py", line 113, in __init__
    raise ValueError("expected parenthesized list: %r" % paren)
ValueError: expected parenthesized list: '-api-python-client'
```

How do I instruct setuptools that this library should not considered a version predicate, essentially ignore the hyphen and include everything as the library name?

Comment: You can improve your prospects of getting an answer here by posting the contents of `setup.py`. It's difficult to guess what's going on with regards to `"google-api-python-client"`. The problem may have nothing to do with the name of that package.

Comment: I just figured out what was wrong.  If you use `requires = []` it uses version predicates from the distutils style setup() function.  If however, you use `install_requires = []` with some slight changes to the list items (spaces instead of brackets for version predicates), it works fine.

Comment: go ahead and make that an answer and mark your answer as best so this closes out then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what was wrong. If you use `requires = []` it uses version predicates from the distutils style setup() function. If however, you use `install_requires = []` with some slight changes to the list items (spaces instead of brackets for version predicates), it works fine.